# troubles with data bags in chef/knife

Tags: chef-infra, knife

i try to create users on remote system by chef/knife, but something goes wrong...
here is my steps:

1. installing "user" cookbook

> knife cookbook site install user

1. creating data bag for it

> knife data bag create users

1. creating a json file with options

> cat data_bags/users/fatal.json
>      {
>          "id": "fatal",
>          "uid": "1002",
>          "home": "/home/fatal",
>          "groups": "sudo",
>          "shell": "/bin/bash",
>          "password": "$6$wkWXnXUk$xjaISNyG3cDGU2XYBAf."
>        }

1. exporting it in my data bag

> knife data bag from file users data_bags/users/fatal.json

1. adding recipe "user" to my remote node

> knife node chef-test-client show
>      Node Name:   chef-test-client
>      Environment: _default
>      FQDN:        chef-test-client
>      IP:          192.168.16.777
>      Run List:    recipe[group], recipe[user]
>      Roles:
>      Recipes:     group, user
>      Platform:    debian 7.1
>      Tags:

1. uploading it on knife server

> knife cookbook upload user

1. synchronizing on my remote node

> chef-client
>      Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.0
>      resolving cookbooks for run list: ["group::data_bag", "user::data_bag"]
>      Synchronizing Cookbooks:
>        - user
>        - group
>      Compiling Cookbooks...
>      Converging 0 resources
>      Chef Client finished, 0 resources updated

so nothing happens, user is not created; what am i doing wrong ?, guys please help me to deal with it

UPDATE:

in USAGE section on http://fnichol.github.io/chef-user/

> To use recipe[user::data_bag], include it in your run_list and have a data bag called  >"users"

so i changed my Run List settings to:

```
knife node show chef-test-client  
Node Name:   chef-test-client  
Environment: _default  
FQDN:        chef-test-client   
IP:          192.168.16.777  
Run List:    recipe[user::data_bag], recipe[group::data_bag]  
Roles:         
Recipes:     user::data_bag, group::data_bag  
Platform:    debian 7.1
```

and my data bag:

```
knife data bag show users fatal  
groups:   sudo  
home:     /home/fatal  
id:       fatal  
password:  >$6$wkWXnXUk$xjaISNyG3cDGU2X  
shell:    /bin/bash  
uid:      1002
```

and nothing happens again :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this cookbook: http://fnichol.github.io/chef-user/

According to that description, I think that you have to explicitly add the `fatal` user to `node[:users]`.

Comment: can u please tell me in which file of this cookbook i must add this string, it has been difficult to me :(

Answer (score 1):

StephenKing is right. you must add: default["users"] = ["users", "to", "load"] to your attributes. I think the idea is that the data bag has all of the domains users, but each node decides what users to load from the data bag by name.